# List all tags in use on stackoverflow

Tags: support, tags, api

I am trying to list all tags used on stackoverflow here: http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/methods/tags and I cannot seem to list all.

How do I do it?.

Answer (score 5):

**Update:**
Version 1 of the API is long shut down.  Here's sample paging on API version 2:

- [/2.2/tags?page=1&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=popular&site=stackoverflow](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags#page=1&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=popular&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true)
- [/2.2/tags?page=2&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=popular&site=stackoverflow](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags#page=2&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=popular&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true)
- etc...

---

---

Obsolete, version 1 answer:

```
http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/tags?pagesize=100&page=1

http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/tags?pagesize=100&page=2

etc...
```

Comment: Yes,that did list.Clicking call method without even entering anything lists all in json.

Comment: As of today (3/18/2014) there are 364 pages of that.

Comment: As of today there is "error": { "code": 500 .. }

Comment: API v1.x Shutdown...

Comment: I ran the `v2.2` query and got results, but I don't see the `Tag` url slug for the `Tag` name? Any idea how the url slug is generated for a given tag?