# How to include answers when fetching questions?

Tags: support, api, questions, answers

I made a small cron job which crawls questions and answers from Stack Overflow.

Here is my request URL:

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?order=desc&tagged=php&site=stackoverflow&filter=withbody&no_expiry=true&pagesize=100&key=[my_app_key]access_token=[my_acc_token]
```

It returns the 100 latest questions in the PHP tag perfectly. But, **I would like to include the answers** of the questions too (if it is answered).

I have checked the filters section of documentation but I didn't get it exactly. Can anyone point me to the correct direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The various `/questions` routes do allow you to simultaneously retrieve answers, if you set the right [filter](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters).

**A good starting filter for getting questions with answers is: `!gB7hjL3lhJ*Cnfe63rh6pAm74J(5qrOZKbL`**

## To Customize a Filter:

1. Go to [the `/questions` documentation page](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions).
2. Scroll to the Filter Edit Tool:

   [image: Filter edit tool]
3. Click on the tool and this dropdown appears:

   [image: Filter dropdown]
4. Adjust the filter to return just the fields you want without any cruft:

   1. First type `withbody` into the text box and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  This presets many of the fields in a good way.
   2. Then expand the various groups and adjust which fields are checked.
      For example, click on `badge_count` and then click the `unselect all badge_count fields` link.
   3. It is recommended that you zero out: `badge_count`, `original_question`, `related_site`, and `styling`.  These are almost always unneeded clutter.
   4. **Here is the critical part:**
      **Expand the `question` group and check `answers`.**
   5. Expand the other fields and **uncheck items you do not want.**  You probably do not need to check any additional items, except in the `.wrapper` group.

      **Be careful about checking [`private_info` properties](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question).**  If you do have any of these checked, your API calls will fail unless you also pass a valid `access_token`.
5. Click the <kbd>save</kbd> button.
6. If you break the filter, repeat step 4 but enter `!gB7hjL3lhJ*Cnfe63rh6pAm74J(5qrOZKbL` as the starting point.

---

Also note that **you do not need a `key` or an `access_token` for most requests to `/questions`.**
It's only needed if your filter returns one of the few protected properties and, since you are fetching all recent questions, these properties will almost never apply anyway.

Comment: Thank you. It worked (after removing the access_token part) :). Right now it returns 100 questions in a single request. Is it possible to increase it ? Sorry if I am taking this question to next level, just asking. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: No. You can only get 100 results at a time.  To get more, use [paging](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/paging).  See [this answer](http://stackapps.com/a/2355/7653) for an example of paging.